# Combination selection

Tags: combinations

A family goes to the animal shelter to select three pet cats. THe shelter currently has 27 cats. At the shelter there are 10 long-haired cats and 17 short haired cats.

How many ways are there for the family to make their selection if they want two long hard cats and one short haired cat?

Is it C(10,2) + 17 or c(10,2) x 17?

Comment: This would be better in http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can choose any pair out of 10 long-haired cats and any cat among 17 short-haired ones.

The number of *possible choices* is thus C(10, 2)*17 = 10*9/2 * 17 = 17 * 45.

However, if you take the question *literally*, then the family has 17+10 = 27 cats to choose from. That's why the answer is 27. I think your professor should have asked *"How many cats are there for the family to choose from (as opposed to the number of possible choices)?"* to emphasize that the question should be taken literally.

Comment: 10 long haired cats. So is it C(10,2)*17?

Comment: THats what I thought but my professor says it's wrong...? He says you add them?? Which I don't get why? Is he wrong?

Comment: Well, do you differentiate between the cats or not?

Comment: It doesn't specify in the question. I posted the entire question